# How to stop shifting of content when screen is rotated form portrait to landscape view in mobile devices?

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, responsive-design

The content is getting displaced in the viewport when screen is rotated from portrait view to landscape view and viceversa.

It only happens when I see the middle or end part of the html document.

[you can see the problem hare but try to open it in mobile browser or try using combination ctrl-shift-m on mozilla](http://hututoo.com/D/orentation.html)

I tried different viewport settings but nothing seems to be working.

```
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

And one more thing if we make the height of images fixed then it start working in the right manner .But due to its responsive nature I think its not good to give images a fixed height.

Pleas suggest your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for taking interest in my question.
I was thinking it was an css issue or html bug but I fixed it with small jQuery code. 
Also see the [working example](http://www.hututoo.com/D/orentation1.html)

```
            jQuery(function(){
            jQuery.miniMenu = new Object();
            jQuery.miniMenu.i = new Object();

            jQuery(document).on("scroll", function(){
                var scroll_position = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
                var doc_height = jQuery(document).height();
                var w_height = jQuery(window).height();
                var b_h = doc_height-w_height;
                var scroll = (scroll_position/b_h)*100;
                jQuery.miniMenu.i.globalVar = scroll;
                console.log("scroll position "+scroll);
            });

            jQuery(window).click(function(){
                console.log("new scroll "+jQuery.miniMenu.i.globalVar);
                var scroll_position = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
                var doc_height = jQuery(document).height();
                var w_height = jQuery(window).height();
                var b_h = doc_height-w_height;
                var scroll = (scroll_position/b_h)*100;
                console.log("scroll position "+scroll);
            });

            jQuery(window).on('orientationchange', orientationChangeHandler);
            console.log("orentation change");
            function orientationChangeHandler(e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var doc_height = jQuery(document).height();
                    var scroll = jQuery.miniMenu.i.globalVar;
                    var w_height = jQuery(window).height();
                    var b_h = doc_height-w_height;
                    var scroll_position = (scroll*b_h)/100;
                    scroll_position = Math.round(scroll_position);
                    jQuery('html, body').animate( {scrollTop: scroll_position}, "5", function(){
                        console.log("animation complete");  
                    });
                    console.log(scroll_position);
                }, 20);
            }
        });
```